# File Not Found Error when loading an asset in XNA Game Studio 4.0

Tags: c#, exception, xna, xna-4.0

I am making a program for a school project and I am new to XNA Game Studio. For some reason even though the file is in Content. I am getting a ContentLoadException occured in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll on the code,

```
spriteSheet = Content.Load<Texture2D>("mario-2");
```

The code is in the Scene class I created in the initScene function, and the initScene is called after SpriteBatch is created in the LoadContent function on the generated default Game1 class.

I checked the properties of mario-2.png, and the asset name matches the one used and the Content Importer and Content Processer are set to Texture - XNA FrameWork.

Content's RootDirectory was set to "Content" when Game1 was constructed.

Comment: Is your "mario-2.png" file in the root directory of "Content" or a sub-directory?

Comment: Its in the root I believe, it is not in any folder within the (Content) section.

Comment: Can you show a picture of your solution structure (more specifically, the Content project) and the properties window of the image inside the project?

Comment: Here is a picture that show where the exception happened in the code, The project structure, and the image properties.

http://i.imgur.com/m8kCtTM.png

Comment: And who calls the metod "InitScene"?

Comment: LoadContent() from the Game1 class. initScene is called after SpriteBatch is created.

Comment: try `Build Action = Content` and `Output Directory = Copy if Newer`

Comment: Exception still happens with those settings.

Comment: Off the top of my head, it sounds like a clean reinstall of XNA would fix this. But before doing so, try manually copy the image (yes, as PNG) into the ProjectFolder\Bin\Debug\Content folder and see if it runs then.

Answer (score 0):

Check these two things:

1.) Is the image compiled into xnb and in the content folder?  I'm not certain that placing the uncompiled image in there will work.

2.) Check the asset name in the properties window of the xnb file to ensure it matches the string you specified in your content.load method.